# Is it possible to make a windows explorer context menu associated to both a file name extension and the result of peeking at the contents?

Tags: c#, windows, explorer

I would like to know if it's possible to write a context menu extension that, upon right clicking, would open the file and look at the first few bytes, changing the resulting menu items that appear.

Comment: Of course it is possible.  You see it done all the time.  It's exremely BAD practice though. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/10/03/10218997.aspx

Comment: if i make a service that writes metadata to a database, would a connection+query overhead be acceptable you think?

Comment: I still don't think that's a good idea.  If the database goes down you just lost your menu.. at the very best your use waits ~10 sec while the connection tries to time out, worst case you crash explorer.  If you have to read file contents/access resources, perhaps a shell context menu is the wrong UI choice here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

Context Menu Shell Extensions allow you to implement an interface which, once registered, is called by the system to determine what menu items you want to display. During the call, you could open the file, read the data and selectively choose which menu items to display.

I would advise not doing this in C# however - the [IContextMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776095%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and other interfaces are designed more for a C++ implementation.

Edit: Microsoft officially [does not support writing shell extensions with managed code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd758089%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: While it's possible, it is not recommended because that means you are accessing the disk on the UI thread, which can lead to hangs. (Imagine if the file is on a network server halfway around the world, or if it has been archived to tape.)

Comment: Also, MS officially do not support writing shell extensions with managed code

Comment: Besides not supporting it, its been shown several times (do a google search) that injecting a .NET dependancy into Exporer is a bad idea.

Comment: i'm fine with C++, but i'm glad i asked this with the c# tag so I knew not to try C#